# Request body is overwriting the HTTP method?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Objective:** To obtain the method by which a resource (route) on AWS-API Gateway was called.

**My progress:** I have an endpoint which has GET, PATCH, POST methods, mapped on to a template during the integration request step. The template for PATCH looks like this:

```
"editJobsTemplate": {
     "application/json": {
     "method": "$context.httpMethod",
     "job": "$input.json('$.job')"
    }
 }
```

created using [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html).

**Problems:** When the PATCH body is empty I get the reponse like:

```
{
  "eventType": {
    "method": "PATCH",
    "job": ""
  }
}
```

but when there is an object with 'job' as a key sent in the body...

```
{
  "job":"some text value"
}
```

then the response looks like:

```
{
  "eventType": {
     "job": "some text value"
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

[This](https://snag.gy/hCmd39.jpg) is a screenshot of the template from the API Gateway Resource panel.

and I tested on Postman with to get [this result](https://snag.gy/K4zSIj.jpg)

**EDIT 2**
[This](https://snag.gy/jXitEZ.jpg) is to show the Content-Type header being set to application/json, as per the response from b.b3rn4rd, and [this](https://snag.gy/AraG0s.jpg) shows the response I get thereafter.

Comment: Is the first code paste actually the template or is that the swagger excerpt? Have you tested this in the console using the Test feature?

Comment: I am using serverless for my deployments, so I have added screenshots to address to your comment, the first paste is the template. I have also added screenshots for the test on postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you calling your endpoints make sure you specify appropriate content-type header . In your case its probably is `Content-Type: application/json`, otherwise, request mapping will be skipped and request will be passed to (lambda ?) as it is.

Also, I can already spot, another potential issue with `"job": "$input.json('$.job')"`,

should be:

`"job" : $util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$.job'))` 
**no quotes !**

Comment: I have added the header, I added the screenshots in my edit. I now get a bad string as response. I am just running a test to get the method from a request so didn't use the escapeJavaScript utility, thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: I did not doubt that, had similar issue when began using gateway :)